# Mybatis plus returning no rows when IS NULL check included in where clause

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, mybatis-plus

No rowing returning while checking reqstatus is null in where clause using mybatis plus

```xml
<select id="fetchrow" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
    SELECT * FROM USERS 
    <where>
    reqstatus IS NULL
    AND reqFlag IS NULL
    AND rownum &lt;= 3
    FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
    </where>
<select>
```

MyBatis generated query is working in SQL Developer and returning data where as MyBatis Plus returns no rows.

```
ID  NAME     ReqStatus Reqflag
12  sandhya   (null)    (null)
13  custre    (null)    (null)
14  ewrd      s          t
```

The above is the table data

Comment: Show the table data. Show us that there are some rows where both those columns are NULL. BTW Surely it should be `&lt;`?

Comment: Added the table data

Comment: Why you need the rownum? giving your data it seem it is normal to return no values because of this.

Comment: I have bulk data in table need to fetch based on limit in table

Comment: Surely you should be using the `LIMIT` clause? and an `ORDER BY`? Otherwise if the first three rows in the table don't match, you get nothing. Is that what you want? Really?

Comment: @user207421 This is in XML, so `<=` needs to be encoded as `&lt;=`.

Comment: No data retrieved from mybatis as a result able to see the data in table

Comment: You should look at `v$sql`, find your query, and see whether it is correct. When getting Oracle errors or incorrect data, it's important to see the actual SQL that was submitted to the database layer rather than how it's coded in the front-end. What if it's stripping the `&lt;` out? You don't know until you verify.

Comment: Able to get the result by executing generated sql query of MyBatis in oracle where as mybatis returns result as no data